# Cannot run a natural join

Tags: sql, sql-server, natural-join

I have two tables:

- A table `takes` with attributes `ID` and `Course_ID`
- A table `course` with attributes `Course_ID`, `title`, and `dept_name`

I want to retrieve `title` and `dept_name` using a natural join on the two tables, but it returns an error:

> incorrect syntax near ';'

My code:

```
select title, dept_name
from takes 
natural join course;
```

What is wrong with my code?

PS. My textbook does not mention using the `on` keyword. Besides that, it also mentions to use the operator `using` to specify the common attributes, but this doesn't help either.

Comment: Please add the table create statement.

Comment: SQL server doesn't support natural join.

Comment: Using natural joins is highly discouraged anyway due to the pitfalls that stem from matching the names - natural join does **not** use the foreign keys defined. It only matches column names. So if you later add e.g. a `created_at` column to both tables, those would _also_ be used for the join.

Answer (score 1):

Well standard `SQL` supports a concept called `natural join`, which represents an `inner
join` based on a match between columns with the `same name` in both sides. For example,
`T1 NATURAL JOIN T2` joins the rows between `T1` and `T2` based on a match between the
columns with the same names in both sides. 
T-SQL being a dialect of `SQL`, doesn’t have an implementation of a `natural join`, as of `SQL Server 2012`. 
So in your case as `takes` and `course` has a common column `Course_ID` , equivalent representation in `T-SQL` will be:

```
select C.title, C.dept_name
from takes T
INNER JOIN course C on C.Course_ID = T.Course_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlserver does not support natural join. Instead of that you can use

> INNER JOIN

```
select c.title, c.dept_name
from takes t
inner join course c on t.Course_ID = c.Course_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Besides that, it also mentions to use the operator using to specify the common attributes, but this doesn't help either.*

You either mis-read the textbook or that textbook is plain wrong. `natural join` does not require *any* specification on which column to use.

The `USING` attribute is used for a "regular" join:

```
select c.title, c.dept_name
from takes t
  join course c using (Course_ID);
```

`join` is equivalent to `inner join`. The keyword `inner` is optional.

`join course using (Course_ID)` is equivalent to `join course c on t.course_id = c.course_id`